# MySQL where value dosnt equal

Tags: mysql

Here is my code

```
SELECT * FROM categories
LEFT JOIN cat_meta ON cat_meta.cat_id = categories.cat_id
WHERE cat_meta.meta_key = 'Delete'
AND cat_meta.meta_value <> 1
```

What I want is to retrive all the categories that dont have a `meta_value` of 1. This could mean if the category `meta_value` was not set, or if the `meta_value = 0`.

Instead whats happening is im getting a list of categories that **have been set** to `meta_value = 0`

How should i rewrite this?

Comment: @vinay - Yes it is. It seems my problem is because when the `meta_value` for the category isnt set, the `meta_key` still runs, which eliminates all the categories that havnt been set... I dont know how to fix this.

Comment: As many of them have already suggested, check for the IS NULL condition. It should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to explicitly check for NULL (the other one is to use NVL(), but I don't know whether that is portable):

```
SELECT * FROM categories
LEFT JOIN cat_meta ON cat_meta.cat_id = categories.cat_id
WHERE cat_meta.meta_key = 'Delete'
AND (cat_meta.meta_value <> 1 or cat_meta.meta_value is NULL)
```

Beware: this will *not* return categories that have no entry for meta_key = 'Delete' at all!

Comment: Thanks! i applied IS NULL to the key and the value and that did it.

Answer (score 0):

if meta_value has a default of NULL you can add

```
 cat_meta.meta_value IS NULL OR cat_meta.meta_value <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a NULL check (if the meta_value is nullable):

```
SELECT * FROM categories
LEFT JOIN cat_meta ON cat_meta.cat_id = categories.cat_id
WHERE cat_meta.meta_key = 'Delete'
AND cat_meta.meta_value IS NULL OR cat_meta.meta_value <> 1
```